# Model Validation using Fluent Validation on WEB API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I am trying to use fluent validation for my models on Web API project. I have two classes name `OrderHeader` and Items . And i have property name as `OrderQty` on Items class which is an integer and i have applied a rule for OrderQty as it should be number only (i.e. 0-9) . whenever i get the JSON request for `OrderQty` as alphanumeric (like 1A) i cannot serialize the JSON and could not get the errormessage from fluent validation on `Modelstate` . How to achieve this could someone help me on this please ? Thanks in advance !!!

I have tried to convert the `OrderQty` to `ToString()` and applied rule but i could not get the errormessage while serialiaing the JSON .

My modal classes :

```
public class OrderHeader
{
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Created { get; set; }
    public List<Items> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Items
{
   public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public int OrderQty { get; set; }
   public double Weight { get; set; }
   public double Price { get; set; }
   public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent Validations

```
public class OrderHeaderValidator : AbstractValidator<OrderHeader>
{

    public OrderHeaderValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.OrderNumber.Trim()).NotEmpty().WithMessage("OrderNumber : cannot be blank.").Length(1, 6).WithMessage("OrderNumber : cannot be more than 6 characters.").Matches("^[0-9]*$").WithMessage("OrderNumber : must contains only numbers");
        RuleFor(x => x.Items).SetCollectionValidator(new ItemValidator());
    }
}


public class ItemsValidator : AbstractValidator<Items>
{

    public ItemsValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.OrderQty.ToString()).NotNull().WithMessage("TotalOrderQuantity : cannot be blank").Matches("^[0-9]*$").WithMessage("TotalOrderQuantity : must contains only numbers");
        RuleFor(x => x.Status.ToUpper()).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Status : Provide the Status").Length(0, 1).WithMessage("Status : cannot be more than 1 character").Matches("O").WithMessage("Status : Must be 'O'");

    }

}
```

Serializing and getting error message :

```
 string errors = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ModelState.Values
                .SelectMany(state => state.Errors)
                .Select(error => error.ErrorMessage));
```

I expect the output should be if the value for is 1A from JSON request then it displays the error message as:

> TotalOrderQuantity : must contains only numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can't deserialize `1A` into `int OrderQty`. Use `string OrderQty` instead and check `.Must(x => int.TryParse(x.OrderQty, out _))` in validator.

It's OK that your API has specification like `OrderQty must be integer` - `int OrderQty`. If someone tries to send string instead of integer - you can catch deserializion exception and reject the request with message like `invalid request: ...`

Comment: I used like RuleFor(x=>x.OrderQty).Must(validateint).WithMessage("Must be integer");

And my validateint function is like 

 public bool validateint(string value)
 {
       int number;
       bool a = int.TryParse(value, out number);
       return a;
 }
 
 Its works great !!! but how can i show the errormessage as which item having an invalid OrderQty in a list of items in the model

Comment: Like how can i append the ItemNumber in Error Message . I tried below,
 
 RuleFor(m => new { m.OrderQty, m.ItemNumber }).Must(x => validateint(x.OrderQty, x.ItemNumber))
                                     .WithMessage(string.Format("A {0}",x.ItemNumber));
          
But i could not make it success

Comment: @Vicky Try this `.WithMessage(x => $"A{x.ItemNumber}")`

Comment: I am getting the compile time errors like Unexpected character '$' and some errors

Comment: I uesed like this RuleFor(m => new { m.OrderQty, m.ItemNumber }).Must(x => validateint(x.OrderQty, x.ItemNumber)).WithMessage(x => $"A{x.ItemNumber}");

Comment: @Vicky Why do you need this `RuleFor(m => new { m.OrderQty, m.ItemNumber })`?

Comment: @Vicky Why do you pass two parameters here `validateint(x.OrderQty, x.ItemNumber)`?

Comment: This is for the value OrderQty is belongs to that item . If the OrderQty is not a number like (0-9) i need to send a error message as WithMessage(Item 123456 must be integer);

Comment: `RuleFor(m => m).Must(x => int.TryParse(x.OrderQty, out _)).WithMessage(x => $"A{x.ItemNumber}")`

Comment: @Vicky Please accept my answer if it helped you to fix the issue.